# wp-cli create post and media import

Tags: wp-cli

I would like to create a post and insert a url as an image, right now I have this, it works but creates a gallery block, instead I would just like to create a simple image block . What is the correct syntax to post just an image in "post_content" ?

```
 wp post create --post_title="test" --post_content="[gallery ids='$(wp media import https://ring.cdandlp.com/113719298.jpg --porcelain)']"
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just `[gallery]` to display images BUT you can specify in which size the image(s) will be displayed. By default it's `size='thumbnail'`. Simply set it to `size='full'` to just get one full-sized image:

```
$ wp post create --post_title="Foobar" --post_content="[gallery ids='$(wp media import https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg --porcelain)' size='full']"
```

More gallery shortcode options can be found on wordpress.com: https://en.support.wordpress.com/gallery/#gallery-shortcode